# How can I grant authenticated users access to other properties in Firebase and React Native? [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I'm really new to Firebase and React Native and I'm building a user-based app. In Firebase, users are authenticated with a token and they seem to be restricted when it comes to personal properties. As far as I understood, how it works is, users are automatically assigned with both token and userId. And if you want to add additional info you create an object in the Realtime Database to store users and you assign said users with the ID they belong.

So what I have is a couple of users and I have two user objects with some properties.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVbnC.png)

I'm using Axios to do a GET request only for authenticated users:

```
`    const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
      const token = authCtx.token;
      // console.log(token);
     useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get(
            "https://fbapp-(heart)-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=" +
              token
          )
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
          });
      }, [token]);`
```

My firebase rule is:

```
`    {
      "rules":{
        ".write": "auth.uid != null ",
        ".read" : "auth.uid != null"
      }
    }`
```

The issue here is that with those rules each authenticated user gets access to the Realtime DB. So after some research, I've found out that I can set my rules like so:

```
`    {
      "rules": {
        "users":{
          "$user_id":{
            ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id",
            ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id"
        }
       }
      }
    }`
```

As far as I understood that rule's for all the users, that have the user_id property and only those users with the current UID can access them. But that's when I get the following error:

WARN:Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401]

The documentation says that auth variable contains uid (A unique user ID assigned to the requesting user). The user is authenticated successfully but still doesn't work. Please help!
Thank you in advance^^

UPDATE:I've found a way to make it work, but I think there's a security issue with the solution. Instead of naming the users "user1, user2,..." I tried naming them with the UID and change my url to:
"https://fbapp-(not here)-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users/"+{user_id}+ ".json?auth="+{token}
Not sure if that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `access_token` to authenticate REST requests.

```
`https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/users.json?access_token=${token}`
```

See [Authenticate with an access token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_access_token) for details.